# Silverlight C# WP - Listing attributes names of a class

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

How to list, by binding, all properties name of a class

```
<ListBox>
<TextBlock Name="{Binding WHAAAAT???!}" />
</ListBox>
```

Class:

```
public class DaysOfWeek
{    
    public bool Monday {get; set;}
    public bool Tuesday { get; set; }
    public bool Wednesday { get; set; }
    public bool Thursday { get; set; }
    public bool Friday { get; set; }
    public bool Saturday { get; set; }
    public bool Sunday { get; set; }
}
```

I'd like to put this content on an list box.
Please, help me with this.

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday 
Thursday 
Friday 
Saturday
Sunday
```

Grateful.

Comment: your DaysOfWeek should be an enum and then you should have a CurrentDay property of type DaysOfWeek in another class

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you will need to use reflection as shown [here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-property-names/)

```
using System.Reflection;  // reflection namespace

// get all public static properties of MyClass type
PropertyInfo[] propertyInfos;
propertyInfos = typeof(MyClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public |
                                              BindingFlags.Static);
// sort properties by name
Array.Sort(propertyInfos,
        delegate(PropertyInfo propertyInfo1, PropertyInfo propertyInfo2)
        { return propertyInfo1.Name.CompareTo(propertyInfo2.Name); });

// write property names
foreach (PropertyInfo propertyInfo in propertyInfos)
{
  Console.WriteLine(propertyInfo.Name);
}
```

Comment: Might use a converter that gets the type and returns the list of public properties for it.

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
Classes.DaysOfWeek _DaysOfWeek;

_DaysOfWeek = new Classes.DaysOfWeek();
var listProp = _DaysOfWeek.GetType().GetProperties().ToList();

List<String> newList = new List<String>{};
foreach(var item in listProp){
newList.Add(item.Name);
}
listBox_Days.ItemsSource = newList;
```

Easy to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Look into the MVVM model (by example creating a new Panorama / Pivot / Databound sample application)
this is the model which will decrease the most amount of time while trying to write new code, 
and staying very clean meanwhile.

Good luck ;)